# In a content-based recommender systems, how to judge per-user rather than per-rating?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-optimization, recommendation-engine

I'm studying the recommender systems from the Andrew Ng course on Coursera, and this question popped into my mind.

In the course, Andrew does recommendations for movies, like Netflix does.
We have an *output* matrix `Y` of ratings of various movies, where each cell `Y(i,j)` is the rating given by user `j` to movie `i`. If the user has not rated it, `Y(i,j)=?`

Assuming we are doing linear regression, we had the following minimization objective:

[image]

My question is, doesn't this calculate on a per-rating basis? As in, all ratings are equal. So if someone rates 100 movies, he has more effect on the algorithm than someone who rates only 10 movies.

I was wondering if it is possible to judge on a per-user basis, i.e. all users are equal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is definitely possible to apply a weight to the loss function with either `weight = 1/ratings_for_user[u]` or `weight = 1/sqrt(ratings_for_user[u])`. where `ratings_per_user[u]` is the number of rating for the user who gave the rating in your particular sample. Whether it's a good idea or not is another question.

To answer that question, I would first ask the question: Is this more meaningful to the problem you are really trying to solve? If it is, as the second question: Does the model you built work well? Does it have a good cross validation score?

Comment: I knew it! I actually guessed exactly this answer, though admittedly I got the idea from the slide just before the one in the picture :)

I actually debated whether doing per-user was good idea for a while. I guess that "ratings have equal weight" is better than "users have equal weights", because in the latter case, a malicious user can make a lot of accounts and rate a particular product badly. And in the former case, users who rate more movies would probably be better at it (like film or fashion critics etc).

Comment: It really depends on your application. For many things in machine learning there isn't one answer. You need to make a decision on what metrics matter to your application, then answer the question can you build a model that does a good job of predicting them.

Comment: I'll remember that :). My previous comment and its subsequent reasoning was in the context of big websites like Amazon and Netflix, for whom malicious users is an issue.

Comment: Yes. There is a reason why Netflix offered a $1M prize for an improved recommendation engine. http://www.netflixprize.com/ There are lots of ways to improve on models. the weighting strategies I suggested are similar to L1 and L2 feature normalization in other contexts. http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.normalize.html